# jQueryUI + RequireJS + AngularJS throws exceptions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs, requirejs

I'm using jQueryUI in combination with RequireJS and AngularJS.  I wrapped the jqueryui components in require statements like:

```
define(['jquery','./core','./mouse', './widget'], function (jQuery) {
    (function( $, undefined ) {

         $.widget("ui.draggable", $.ui.mouse, {....});
    })(jQuery);

});
```

and created a AngularJS directive to wrap it like:

```
 require(['angular', 'app', 'jquery', 'lib/jquery-ui/draggable'], function(angular, app, $){

    app.directive('draggable', ['$timeout','draggableConfig', function ($timeout) {
      return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            options: '='
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attributes) {
            $timeout(function(){
                $element.draggable();
            }, 50)
        }
    }
   }]);
});
```

but 2 out of every 5 times the app throws an error like:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'draggable'
at http://localhost/phoenix/directives/draggable.js:21:30
at http://localhost/phoenix/lib/angular/angular.js:13152:28
at completeOutstandingRequest (http://localhost/phoenix/lib/angular/angular.js:3996:10)
at http://localhost/phoenix/lib/angular/angular.js:4302:7
```

I've tried countless things but had no luck consistently.  I'm pretty sure the draggable isn't getting bound to the $ by load time of the directive but the dependencies are right so I'm lost why.  Any thoughts?

Comment: do you think it has somethin to do with the 50 milliseconds of the weird timeout function ? is this a try to avoid the exception ?+

Comment: Ya, I added the $timeout to try to avoid the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directive had `require` when it should have used `define`.

Comment: can you explain? dont understand

Answer (score 0):

Its a timing issue. RequireJs loads the files asynchronously. You need to make jquery-ui a dependency of jquery in the require config.

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'Scripts/App',
    paths: {
        jQueryUI: '../Lib/Jquery/jquery-ui.min',
        jQuery: '../Lib/Jquery/jquery.min'        
    },
    shim: {
        jQueryUI: { deps: ['jQuery'] },
    }
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/c4RmkiskYpEApXRA8Ska?p=preview)

Comment: Okay, that makes sense but I thought the wrapping of the components in require and having jquery be part of that would fix that eh?

Comment: I'm not sure about the wrapping thing, but I added an example to my answer.